# Proceed to credit card payment method in PayPal

Tags: php, magento, paypal

There is a form, which redirects to PayPal on https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr . And shows two ways of payment: login in PayPal and pay with credit card. Is there any way to get redirect right to pay with credit card? Maybe it is need to add some parameter in form or change an action url?

Answer (score 0):

No, it a paypal decision, usually if they now users have paypal account, thy redirect to paypal tab, otherwise if its the first time they redirect to card one, this is a semplicistic explanation,but if you search on paypal doc or consult an account manager(that's what i did) you'll get this answer

Answer (score 0):

For credit cards payment with PayPal you can use [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), example - [CreatePayment.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php).

Comment: Thanks, I saw that library, but I don't need to use it. I use more simple way: form with action url - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. And it redirects to page, where one can choose: login into PayPal, or pay with credit card. I just wanted to get redirect right to credit card payment page without  that page with choosing.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this library https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library
I have created sample also for creditcard payment.
It is very easy to use
Just fill-up array values and your work is ready.
No need to read core functions of paypal.
Find your appropriate file in samples/rest.**